# How to programatically check the available space on Google Drive from an Android app

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file from my Android app which I am able to. But before that I want to check the available space on my Google Drive.

I am using Google Drive API (version 2). I tried multiple option but wasn't able to find that information.

Can someone tell me how to fetch the Google Drive free space.

Comment: please accept the right answer, or say what does not work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at this great sample: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get)

```
private static void printAbout(Drive service) {
   try {
     About about = service.about().get().execute();

     System.out.println("Current user name: " + about.getName());
     System.out.println("Root folder ID: " + about.getRootFolderId());
     System.out.println("Total quota (bytes): " + about.getQuotaBytesTotal());
     System.out.println("Used quota (bytes): " + about.getQuotaBytesUsed());
         // TOTAL - USED = FREE SPACE
   } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
   }

}
```

Comment: This is from the google REST API. The question was about the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sample Java code for the [`About: get`](https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) method, which returns the total quota and the user quota in bytes. Calculating the free space remaining should be a trivial task from there.